# ffmpeg volume parameter format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, parameters, amplification

`ffmpeg's` `-vol` parameter is confusing me.

```
256 => normal (i guess meaning same as input volume, no change)
512 => (double the volume - read this somewhere).
```

So what to do for 3 times the volume? 1.5 times the volume?

Basically, lets say I have the max sound amplitudes (audacity levels) in 3 files as:

```
0.8
0.6
0.9
```

I want to amplify in the first two files, so that `max=0.9` in all files. What parameters of `-vol` I would use?

Comment: Where is the description of that parameter? `man ffmpeg` doesn't show it.

Comment: Same issue. I'm confused too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is really elementary school maths, I suppose.

If 256 is norm (0.8), then you simply have to divide it by normative level and multiply with required level, e.g.

```
256 * 0.9/0.8 = 288
256 * 0.9/0.6 = 384
```

See [cross multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication).

The real question is, how to make ffmpeg output all audio normalized to 1, regardless of current amplitude level.